# How to save changes of dataframe from julia to excel as new excel?

Tags: julia

I have an excel file that I have read and did some calculation to make two new columns. I added them to  dataframe by:

```
df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable(data_file_path, "sheet1"))
df[!, :new] = new_columns_data_values
df[!, :newer] = newer_columns_data_values
```

When I call `df` julia shows that these new columns are added to the original dataframe. But the changes are not reflecting on excel file too. How to save new data frame as a new excel file?

Comment: see https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/tutorial/#Export-Tabular-Data-from-any-Tables.jl-compatible-source

Comment: Your dataframe is updated in memory. To save it on disk you have to perform another operation.

Answer (score 1):

Thank @Bogumił Kamiński for the link, I did give it a try and worked!

```
XLSX.writetable("new_file.xlsx", "sheet1" => df)
```